# How to get the access token of Facebook app via curl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to get the access token of a Facebook app by calling the callback url via curl.

In the first function, I'm trying to constrcut the login url this way:

```
if(!session_start()) {
        session_start();
    }

    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id'     => '',
        'app_secret' => '',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $callback = 'http://www.exemple.com/callback';

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback);
```

In the callback page, I'm getting the access token and forcing the page to exit to display it in JSON

```
  if(!session_start()) {
    session_start();
}

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id'     => '',
    'app_secret' => '',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // There was an error communicating with Graph
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    $data['access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    $data = json_encode($data);
    die($data);
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
    exit;
}
```

Finally, I'm using Curl to call this page and getting the result.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    $url = //The loggin url.

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

    return $result;
```

This's not working for me. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to get an access token without user interaction?

Comment: Yes, its a kind of !

Comment: Please clarify: "This's not working for me" - what specifically is not working?

Comment: The whole coding. I'm trying to avoid the user interaction by calling the callback URL via cUrl. I'm getting a empty result.

Comment: ok then. please don´t even try to do that. you can (and should) only get a token with user interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: im pretty sure you need to first log in (via username/password) via curl, before you can authorize an app. you fail because curl isn't logged in... logging in by username/password isn't easy. fortunately, i have the code for logging in via username/password here https://github.com/divinity76/msgme

Comment: automating things like that can get you banned on facebook. and it´s not neccessary anyway, if you need a user token for a longer time just use an extended one. it is valid for 60 days.